# Reading files asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, c#-5.0

I have this code here for reading files:

```
private void ReadFile()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("data.txt"))
        {
            while ((currentline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                currentline = currentline.ToLower();
                currentline = RemoveChars(currentline);
                currentline = RemoveShortWord(currentline);
                AddWords(currentline);
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to read files asynchronous for large files but not sure how to do it here. Could you point in the right directions.

This is what I tried to make it asynchronous:

```
    private async void ReadFile()
    {

        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("dickens.txt"))
        {
            while ((currentline =  await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                currentline = currentline.ToLower();
                currentline = RemoveChars(currentline);
                currentline = RemoveShortWord(currentline);
                AddWords(currentline);
            }
        }
    }
```

It seem that my `AddWords` method is not working (when using asynchronous). This method adds words to a dictionary:

```
    private void AddWords(string line)
    {
        string[] word = line.Split(' ');

        foreach (string str in word)
        {
            if (str.Length >= 3)
            {
                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(str))
                {
                    dictionary[str]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    dictionary[str] = 1;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part gives you problems? What have you tried?

Comment: @svick I made it edit to show what I have tried

Comment: Is this a WinForm project?

Comment: @hbrock what is the problem?

Comment: @DanielA.White I have added an edit

Comment: @SystemDown this is console app right now

Comment: If it's just a console app (no GUI) why are you reading files asynchronously?

Comment: When you say it's not working are you getting exceptions or is your dictionary not getting populated or ... ?

Comment: @MikeParkhill the dictionary is not getting populated

Comment: @SystemDown because the class might be used for an GUI at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid `async void`. The `async` equivalent of a method returning `void` is `async Task`, not `async void`.

Change `private async void ReadFile()` to `private async Task ReadFileAsync()` and `await` the result before using the dictionary.